# SQL SERVER ERROR: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation

Tags: sails-mssqlserver

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 26
> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Comment: lacks context. That error can occur in several situations.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command and resolve the above issue.
**DATABASE_DEFAULT**
i.e

```
update [TableName] set
    [ColumnName] = [i.ColumnName]
from [TableName] i
where i.[ColumnName] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = [TableName].[ColumnName] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).